# Parsing HTML to get contents and it's tag

Tags: java, html, jsoup

This may be an odd question to ask. But with detailed explanation, I might get a solution (at least a kick start point.)

I am working to automate the localization testing (L10N) with `selenium` & `Java`. As a part of one of possible approach,

- I am using HTML `Jsoup` parser in Java to get the plain text of HTML page.
- Further, I want to keep these extracted text, **tagwise** in an
  **Excel file**.

Now As far as I know, Parsers if provided filters will give the corresponding plain text. But Is there any way that I can get the underlying `HTML tag` along with the text? Is it even possible with `Jsoup` or with any other parser?

e.g. I was looking to get `<option>` when I get *Accounts* as parsed text.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <select>
    <option value="Savings">Accounts</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jsoup you can do this,

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<html><body<select><option value=\"Savings\">Accounts</option></select></body></html>");

    String contentText = "Accounts";

    Elements elems = doc.select(":containsOwn(" + contentText + ")");

    for(Element e: elems) {
        System.out.println("Html : " + e.outerHtml());
        System.out.println("Tag  : " + e.tagName());
    }
```

Ouptput

```
  Html : <option value="Savings">Accounts</option>
  Tag  : option
```

Comment: Yes that worked. I missed out the method `e.tagName()`.